# I am trying Spring MVC and got problem about API works(Server)

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, spring-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc0Ti.png)**I checeked JDBC and checked it works.**

**but i'm trying to make Rest api (a.k.a RESTful api) but i got 500 error.**

**Guys, Can u find which part is wrong?**

**ERROR : 500 Interal Server problem**

**javax.servlet.ServletException:**

error details : org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'promotionApiController' defined in file [C:\Users\ICT\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\finalproject\WEB-INF\classes\kr\or\connect\finalproject\controller\PromotionApiController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'kr.or.connect.finalproject.service.PromotionService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

---PromotionApiController.java-------

```
package kr.or.connect.finalproject.controller;
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import kr.or.connect.finalproject.dto.Promotion;
import kr.or.connect.finalproject.service.PromotionService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api/promotions")  
public class PromotionApiController {
    @Autowired 
    PromotionService promotionService;
    
    
    public PromotionApiController(PromotionService promotionService) {
        this.promotionService = promotionService;
    }
    @GetMapping
     
    public List<Promotion> getPromotion() { 
        return promotionService.getPromotion();//promotionService
    };
    
    
}
```

ApplicationConfing.java

```
package kr.or.connect.finalproject.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "kr.or.connect.finalproject.dao",  "kr.or.connect.finalproject.service"}) 

@Import({ DBConfig.class })
public class ApplicationConfig {
}
```

PromotionDao.java

```
package kr.or.connect.finalproject.dao;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import kr.or.connect.finalproject.dto.Promotion;
import static kr.or.connect.finalproject.dao.PromotionDaoSqls.*;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class PromotionDao {
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;
    private RowMapper<Promotion> promotionRowMapper = BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Promotion.class);
    
    public PromotionDao(DataSource datasource) {
        this.jdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource);
    }
    
    public List<Promotion> selectPromotion() {
        return jdbc.query(SELECT_PROMOTION, Collections.emptyMap(), promotionRowMapper);
    }
}
```

PromotionDaoSqls

```
package kr.or.connect.finalproject.dao;

public class PromotionDaoSqls {
    public static final String SELECT_PROMOTION = "select promotion.id as id, promotion.product_id as product_id, save_file_name as productImageUrl \r\n"
            + "from promotion, product_image, file_info \r\n"
            + "where promotion.product_id = product_image.product_id and type='th' and file_info.id=product_image.file_id";
}
```

Promotion.java   (DTO)

```
package kr.or.connect.finalproject.dto;

public class Promotion {
    private int id;
    private int product_id;
    private String productImageUrl;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getProduct_id() {
        return product_id;
    }
    public void setProduct_id(int product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }
    public String getProductImageUrl() {
        return productImageUrl;
    }
    public void setProductImageUrl(String productImageUrl) {
        this.productImageUrl = productImageUrl;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Promotion [id=" + id + ", product_id=" + product_id + ", productImageUrl=" + productImageUrl + "]";
    }
    
}
```

PromotionService.java

```
package kr.or.connect.finalproject.service;

import java.util.List;

import kr.or.connect.finalproject.dto.Promotion;

public interface PromotionService {
    public List<Promotion> getPromotion();
    
}
```

PromotionServficeImpl.java

```
package kr.or.connect.finalproject.service.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import kr.or.connect.finalproject.dao.PromotionDao;
import kr.or.connect.finalproject.dto.Promotion;//promotion의 dto
import kr.or.connect.finalproject.service.PromotionService;

@Service
public class PromotionServiceImpl implements PromotionService{
    @Autowired
     PromotionDao promotionDao;
    
    public PromotionServiceImpl(PromotionDao promotionDao) {
        this.promotionDao = promotionDao;
    }
    
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Promotion> getPromotion() {
        return promotionDao.selectPromotion();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ODTM.png)

Comment: May be because you aren't scanning `kr.or.connect.finalproject.service.impl`

Comment: @tgdavies Can you explain in detail?

Comment: I thought ```kr.or.connect.finalproject.service package includes``` ```kr.or.connect.finalproject.service.impl.```

Comment: Maybe you have 2 classes that implement PromotionService?

Comment: @yuri777 It looks like 2 implement classes. i tried to remove one PromotionService impement, but eclpise deteles both. i think elipse just show us mirrored package.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it should

Comment: @tgdavies OK. then at least it's not a package problem

Comment: Problem solved
Main reason was lack of adding web.xml settings.

Comment: `<context-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
  </param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>kr.or.connect.finalproject.config.ApplicationConfig
  </param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  </listener-class>
 </listener> `

Comment: `<filter>
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
  </filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>encoding</param-name>
   <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>`

Comment: when i added those code in web.xml, it immidiately worked!!